# Update table column using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hi guys I´m trying to update table column by using codeigniter, this is my code below.

Controller:

```
function search2()
{
  if ($_POST) {
      $Interno=$_POST['Interno'];
  }else{
    $Interno = '';
  }
  $this->db->select('empleados.Interno, empleados.Curp, empleados.Nombre, empleados.A_Paterno, empleados.A_Materno, cuentas.Clabe, cuentas.Banco, cuentas.Observaciones, cuentas.Status');
$this->db->from('empleados');
$this->db->join('cuentas',"cuentas.Interno = empleados.Interno AND cuentas.Status !='I'", 'Left');
$this->db->where('empleados.Interno', $Interno);
$q = $this->db->get();
$data = array();
$data['records'] = $q->result_array();
$this ->load -> view('main/indice', $data);  
}

function update_Status() 
        {
    $Interno= $this->input->post('Interno');
    $data = array(
    'Status' => $this->input->post('Inactivo')
       );
      if($this->consultas_M->update_Status($Interno, $data))
     {
       echo " update successful...";
       }
    else
      {
  echo "update not successful...";
     }  
   }
```

With function search2, I display results from two tables (that might be the problem) then I want to change the status of table cuentas to 'I' (inactive it is 'A' active by default). So I just want to update that Status column. But it doesn´t do anything.
This is my model

```
function update_Status($Interno,$data)
    {
   $this->db->where('Interno', $Interno);
   $this->db->update('cuentas', $data);
    }
```

'Interno' is the id from the table and also the input name where that id is displayed.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: did u get any error?

Comment: is your table  is updated or not?

Comment: No, it doesn´t, it sends me to the else condition, "update not sucessful...", and I checked in mysql, and field is not being updated

Comment: make sure `$data` is not empty using `print_r($data);` in your controller and also `$Interno`

Comment: Yea both are empty

Comment: that is reason your table is not upated

Comment: do you know what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: check for `$this->input->post('Inactivo')` and `$this->input->post('Interno')` have proper value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Your controller method `update_Status` should be like this :

```
function update_Status() 
{
    $Interno = $this->input->post('Interno');
    $Status = $this->input->post('Inactivo');

    $data['status'] = ! empty($Status) ? $Status : 'I';
    if ( ! empty($Interno))
    {
        $updated = $this->consultas_M->update_Status($Interno, $data);
        if($updated)
        {
           echo " update successful...";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "update not successful...";
        }  
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Interno  not found ...";
    }    
}
```

*And moreover , you should return `true` or `false` from the `update_Status` method, based on there is any changes in your table or not*

**Note** : `$this->db->affected_rows()` : Displays the number of affected rows, when doing “write” type queries (insert, update, etc.).

Your model method `update_Status` should be like this :

```
function update_Status($Interno,$data)
{
   $this->db->where('Interno', $Interno);
   $this->db->update('cuentas', $data);
   if ( $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 )
   {
      return TRUE;
   }
   else 
   {
     return FALSE;
   }
   /* OR you can simply return like this 
     return $this->db->update('cuentas', $data);
   */
}
```

Comment: now it shows error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE), it says that is on this line in the controller,  $data = array('Status' => $Status);

Comment: missing `;`  there, updated my answer do like this  see there

Comment: Yea I spotted the ";" I tried both codes the one before and the one that you edited later, now it just shows me a blank page, it doesn´t show any error message or anything and I checked on mysql and column wasn´t updated.

Comment: this is because `$Interno` is empty,  to check it add else part in controller see the updated answer

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with the fact that, I´m displaying data from two different tables using left join, but anyways, "Interno" which is the ID is on both tables.

Comment: if you think so , you can check it by giving custom id to `$Interno`  like $Interno = 1; in your controller and check whether it is working or not

Comment: Yea it worked like that the problem that I actually need the input data I´ll see how I can figure it out

Comment: good to hear you got the problem , if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to upvote and check it as green